# i'm not getting the right output sql server nodejs

Tags: node.js, flutter

I try to connect and query my sql server from nodejs with this is the code:

```
const http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var sql = require("mssql");

    var dbconfig = {
        server: "xxxx",
        user: "xxxx",
        password: "xxxx",
        database: "xxxxx",
    };
    sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select PersonID from Persons', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send(recordset);
                console.log(recordset);
            }
            //connect.close();
        });
    });
});
```

and the result is

> '''{"recordsets":[[{"PersonID":1}]],"recordset":[{"PersonID":1}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1]}'''
>    i want the result without recordsets like this :
>
> [{ "PersonID":1 }]'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#query-command-callback), the node `mssql`-library supports multiple queries, which is why you see `recordsets` in your result. In your case - as you only have one select - you can just return the first recordset, i.e.

```
request.query('select PersonID from Persons', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            res.send(result.recordset);
        }
    });
```